# Git Rebase with BitBucket

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I am running into an issue that is throwing me for a spin. I have code in my branch that conflicts with master (in my case develop). It is not a big issue since it is literally 7 lines of code easy to identify.

BitBucket is kind enough to let me know that in order to fix the merge conflict I need to do the following steps.

- git checkout `<branch in question>`
- git pull `<master>` (in my case develop)

  - fix conflicts
  - at this point the command line also provides this guidance
  - "Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
    "git add/rm `<conflicted_files>`", then run "git rebase --continue"."
  - Once I run "git rebase --continue", a new document shows up with the opportunity to change the original commit message. I only close it and the merge continues
- git commit

  - git result into "Successfully rebased and updated `<current branch>`
- git push origin HEAD

  - I would expect to have a successful message that everything is running great and as expected however I keep getting this message:

> On branch `<current branch>`
> Your branch and '`<current branch>`' have
> diverged, and have 4 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
> (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

Ok no problem, lets run git pull... and we have to start all over again as if I had never fixed the merge conflicts.

I was reading other comments with similar issues and found someone pushing code with the -f flag (force). I tried and of course it worked, however my 7 line changes turned into multiple file changes. The merge conflict is gone but I am concern about bloating the main (develop) branch with unnecessary commits.

Comment: I think that given that you have _rebased_ (not merged), histories have diverged (on purpose, because of the rebase) so the error is to be expected. I would expect you to to a force-push into the **feature branch** to replace old history with new history (By the way, in your push command, I wouldn't have expected it to just work with `HEAD`. Is that translated by git to mean `my local checked-out branch into the remote branch of the same name`?)

Comment: As another side comment, what is `git commit` about? It's not used in a rebase, unless you are doing something out of the ordinary.

Comment: @eftshift0: Helmut Granda must have hit a merge conflict or two during the rebase; probably, they have `pull.rebase` configured to `true` so that all pulls run `git rebase`, even those that were supposed to run `git merge`...

Comment: I figured out that it was a rebase.... I just didn't seem to see why commit was involved. It happens to be used if you set up a `reword` on an interactive rebase, but this is not the case So, given that it was unexpected..... that's why I asked.

Comment: @eftshift0, honestly I was confused by the 'git commit' instructions but that is precisely what the Bitbucket GUI was telling me to do. Follow the 4 steps that I have highlighted above. I have used 'git merge' to fix merge conflicts in the past but the team I am on requests to use 'git rebase' and it is new to me so I am trying to learn how to fix this type of issue properly and its my third PR where I run into this. The first two created a new branch and re-added my code, this time I said, that is it! I need to learn how to fix this :).

Comment: That's fine. Rebase can take a little bit to figure out how it works.... once it's under your command, you will try to figure out how you have made it to live this long without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: you need `git push --force-with-lease origin HEAD`.

You're running into this issue because you are using rebase.  (Bitbucket is not relevant here; I snipped that tag.)

A rebase operation is, at its core, a command to Git of the form:

- I have some old commits.  They're... *okay-ish*, but not good enough.
- Please *remove* the old commits, creating some new and improved *replacement* commits to use instead.

When you are done, the old commits are gone(ish<sup>1</sup>), and you are now using the new-and-improved replacement commits.

When you run `git push origin HEAD`, your Git resolves your name `HEAD` to your current branch name—whatever that name is—and acts as if you ran `git push origin branch`.  This has your Git call up their GIt, over at `origin`, send over your new commits, and then ask them—politely—if they would please, if it's OK, set *their* branch name to identify the same last commit that *your* branch name identifies.

Because you used rebase, this *please set branch name ______ (fill in with name) to _______ (fill in with hash ID)* amounts to instructions to *their* Git of the form: *Throw away the same old commits I threw away, using these same replacement commits*.  But they don't know that your new replacement commits *are* replacements, at this point.  They've quite forgotten anything they told you earlier.  They see only that you're asking them to *throw away some commits*.  So they say *No! If I did that, I'd lose some commits.*

To overcome their reluctance to discard commits, you must send them a more-forceful command, rather than a polite request.  You must tell them: *Yes, I know this may discard some commits.  Do it anyway!*  To do this, you must use the `--force` or `--force-with-lease` option on your `git push` command.

The `--force-with-lease` option is "safer", in a sense: when you use this option, your command has the form: *I'd like you to update _____ (fill in the blank with branch name).  I believe your latest commit is _______ (fill in the blank with hash ID).  If so, throw away some commits; use ______ (fill in the blank with hash ID).*  Your Git fills in all the blanks and sends this over.  If their Git hasn't accumulated any *new* commits since the last time your Git talked with their Git, your replacement commits are the right replacements, and if they obey this forceful command, that does the trick.

The `--force` option skips the safety check: *Update ______ (fill in the blank with name) to _____ (fill in the blank with hash ID)!*  As long as nobody *else* added *new* commits since you started your work, this forceful command achieves the same result as the more-cautious `--force-with-lease`.

When you use `git pull` instead of `git push` with a forceful option, you get *their* latest commits—which are the ones you threw out earlier while doing your replacements—and now you have the same problem.  You would get this with any kind of pull, whether using a fetch-and-rebase pull, or a fetch-and-merge pull.  (I personally recommend *avoiding* `git pull`: run `git fetch` yourself, then run either `git merge` or `git rebase` yourself, based on which one you intend.  Then when it goes wrong, you know which command actually failed.  When you use `git pull` to run *two* Git commands for you, and something fails, you may not even know which Git command failed.  But some people find typing a few extra characters difficult.  As you can see based on the length of my answer, I don't have this particular problem. )

---

<sup>1</sup>Git is quite greedy for commits, and reluctant to give any up.  For this reason, and as a backup in case you change your mind, the old commits aren't *really* gone yet.  You have, by default, at least 30 days before they will go away for real.  Recovering them in that 30-day window is mildly painful, though.

Comment: `git push origin HEAD` I didn't know about this. So many hours of typing branch-names :-)

Comment: @eftshift0: it's a cheat, but it is one I use a lot. I worry sometimes that I'll be on an unexpected branch, though. :-)

Comment: My typical push command too :-) What do you mean @torek by "on an unexpected branch"? Do you refer to the possible case where the upstream branch should for once *not* be the one with same name on remote? (Side note : how is that a "cheat"? haha)

Comment: @torek, thank you so much this explanation. I searched the web for a while and no one covers how to fix this issues. There are posts and demos of how to rebase but not how to fix rebase conflicts properly which it is strange. I am assuming once we learn the right way we just move on. I hope this helps others in the future.

Comment: @RomainValeri: when I rebase, I tend to save the old branch (so I end up with foo.0, foo.1, foo.2, and foo which at this point is v3) and sometimes I forget which one I was last looking at. I can accidentally `git push -f origin HEAD` and wind up saving foo.2 when I intended to just leave that locally and update foo. For short branch names, it would be easier to just type `foo`, but I sometimes search for the last push in history and re-use it. (It's more of a brain shortcut than a typing one, for me, which is why it's cheating...)

Comment: Bravo. This is a really well explained answer that has also improved my understanding of Git. If I could give it more than one like, I would.